File upload results in an error - net::ERR_FAILED while uploading word file
This is my code:
var formData = new FormData();
var f = $("#myFile")[0].files[0];

var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

formData.append('__RequestVerificationToken', token);
formData.append("fileUpload", $("#myFile")[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: '/GenAI/GetDataFromFile',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",$('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
    }
});


Your codes for file uploading looks good, could you please share more about the error you are facing? You just mentioned "net::ERR_FAILED while uploading word file", do you mean everything worked well when uploading some other file types?

Hi Tiny Thanks!!!
My code is working for some PDF and for docx files. (but give error on particular docx or pdf files which is just in range of 45-50 kb in size)

Thanks for your confirmation, but this is not enough for narrow down the issue, do you have any other information which might contain more detailed exception?
